# How do I change the port WWAHOST.EXE is using so I can run my Apache

Tags: apache

So when I open my `XAMPP` and try to run `Apache`, it says

5:40:08 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
5:40:08 PM  [Apache]    Port 443 in use by "C:\windows\syswow64\wwahost.exe" with PID 6744!
5:40:08 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:40:08 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:40:08 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

I've gone into my Apache files and tried to change the port to 8080 but it doesn't seem to work. I have gone in to both files, `httpd` and `httpd-ssl`. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error: **Port 443 in use** by "C:\windows\syswow64\wwahost.exe" with PID

In my case my Skype was using Port 443 though the Skype App was closed. so Apache was unable to start properly.

Solution: Goto your task manager and Click on the End task on the app which is using Port 443. (In my case, it was Skype App).

Comment: While this could be a solution, the question is asking about how to *change* this port.